# Can drawings be selected via apps script in Google Docs?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a document with Google drawings that for whatever reason are not selectable within the UI. I am not sure how they were ever placed.

I was hoping to write a script to delete them, but I'm not finding a function that applies to drawings specifically.

I'm wondering if anyone knows a trick to accomplish this..

The closest thing I found was their sample for deleting images:

```
function myFunction() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();

// Remove all images in the document body.
var imgs = body.getImages();
for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
  // Retrieve the paragraph's attributes.
var atts = imgs[i].getAttributes();

// Log the paragraph attributes.
for (var att in atts) {
  Logger.log(att + ":" + atts[att]);
}
  imgs[i].removeFromParent();

}
}
```

Comment: Probably came from  Microsoft .doc file conversion to gdoc.

Answer (score 0):

Never too late (I hope). The trick here is that inline drawings (InlineDrawing) are children of Paragraph or ListItem ([source](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/inline-drawing)).

If you want to remove some **inline** drawings, the code below works for me. If you want to find all drawings, please see the TODO comment. It is a simple code, please enhance it if you intend to use it. Just for reference.

Unfortunately, to this time, I didn't find out how to remove drawings that are not **inline** (drawings that are above or below text). Please forgive my limitation.

```
function eraseSomeDrawingsFromDoc() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  const paragraphs = body.getParagraphs()
  paragraphs.forEach(paragraph => {
    const childIfAny = paragraph.getNumChildren() > 0 && paragraph.getChild(0) //TODO: analyze all children
    const childType = childIfAny && childIfAny.getType()
    const iAmADrawing = childType === DocumentApp.ElementType.INLINE_DRAWING
    if(iAmADrawing) childIfAny.removeFromParent()
  })
}
```